# How to extract feature vectors at every convolutional layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
   # conv1_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 3, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv1_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv1_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv1_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool1
    #here we need sum pooling instead of max pooling

        self.pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv1_2,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool1')
```

I want to extract feature vectors after the convolution layer to pass to my custom function. I am very new to Tensorflow so I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom function is part of the tensorflow graph, you should be able to refer directly to the tensors you have created. e.g. if you want the activations of `conv1_1`, use the tensor stored in `self.conv1_1`.

If your custom function needs the raw numbers, after processing, you can pass the same tensor references into `session.run`, e.g.

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([self.conv1_1], ...)
```

Comment: For instance I have a custom function for pooling and I want to replace this  self.pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv1_2,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool1') with that function. How would I do that?

Comment: I understand it is a naive question but I am very new to this.

Comment: I'm trying not to assume too much :) If you want to add a custom function to say, "pool" to just the single maximum value (as a toy example), you can write your own function: `def mypool(input): return tf.reduce_max(input)` and call it like any other python or tensorflow op function (e.g. `self.pool1 = mypool(self.conv1_2)`). Does that make sense?